# Gstreamer issues when playing from USB Stick

Tags: video, mpv, gstreamer

I use MPV and Parole as my media players.

I have a NAS Drive on my network with a few old videos on.

I have a USB Stick with the very same videos on.

Some of the videos are .MKV, some are .MP4.

All of the videos on my NAS Drive play fine on both MPV and Parole.

However, when attempting to play some of the videos from the USB in Parole, I get the following error popup:

```
GStreamer backend error
Could not determine type of stream.
```

When I attempt to open them with MPV via terminal, I get the following output in terminal:

```
Failed to recognize file format.
Exiting ... (Errors when loading file)
```

If I attempt to open them with MPV through the right-click menu, MPV simply doesn't open.

One thing I've noticed that is probably key to the whole thing is that some of the videos have self-related icons, and some share a standard system icon. The ones with self-related icons always play. Some of the ones with the standard system icon play, some of them don't.

Temporarily assuming the issue isn't good old-fashioned data corruption, are there some specific lib files I should make sure I have?

If not, what else should I consider?